# Correctness of Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, shortest-path, correctness-proof, loop-invariants

This question is about the correctness proof of Dijkstra's algorithm in the third edition of *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen et al. (pages 660–661).

The proof makes a case that considering path $p$ is the shortest path that connects a vertex in set $S$ (set of vertices where the distance of nodes to node $s$, the starting node, is minimal) to  a vertex in set $u$ in $V-S$. It then considers the first vertex as $y$ in set $V-S$ along the path $p$. It argues that $y.d \leq u.d$ which is intuitive as $y$ precedes $u$ in set $V-S$. The second argument that since both $u$ and $y$ were in $V-S$ when $u$ was chosen thus $u.d \leq y.d$. I have following two doubts about the second argument:

1. Why were $y$ and $u$ both in $V-S$ when $u$ was chosen? We know by our construction that when both $u$ and $y$ are in $V-S$, then $y$ will be chosen before $u$.
2. The node $u$ is chosen such that when it's added to set $S$ it is not at the minimum distance from node $s$. How is this used in this proof?

Comment: It seems that the question will be hard to answer without possession of the (admittedly common) textbook. Perhaps you should ask your TA instead of here.

Comment: Here's the proof listed http://serverbob.3x.ro/IA/DDU0150.html As in cormen

Comment: But because both vertices u and y were in V - S when u was chosen in line 5, we have d[u] ≤ d[y].? How do we know that when both u and y was in set V-S the vertex chosen is u and not y? Where is the fact that node u when added to set S, it is not at the minimum distance from start node s utilized? Please help

Answer (score 1):

In answer to both of your questions:

Firstly, note that during the maintenance phase of the loop invariant proof, we are in the process of inserting *u* into *S*, and the way that *y* is defined is that it is a node in *V\S* while this is happening, therefore *u* and *y* exist in *V\S* at the same time when *u* is inserted. This answers your first question.

Secondly, note that in the proof, we assume that *u.d* ≠ *δ(s,u)*. It therefore follows that there would be a pair of nodes *x* and *y* (such that *π(y)=x* such that *x ∈ S* and *y ∈ V\S*) such that *y ≠ u* and therefore *y* must come **before** *u*, because otherwise from the Convergence Property it would automatically follow that *u.d = δ(s,u)* which would be a contradiction to our assumption. Therefore from here it must follow that *y* comes before *u*. But note that from the first point I made above, *y* must come **after** *u*. And this is exactly the whole point of the proof, both of these things cannot happen simultaneously unless *y.d = δ(s,y) = δ(s,u) = u.d*.

Note that we used the assumption that *u* is not the minimal distance from *s* when added to *S* by showing that we reach a contradiction if we assume this.